# Angular not loading when running Karma tests (following a tutorial)

Tags: angular, karma-runner

I am trying to learn about how to take a Test Driven Development approach when writing Angular apps; I have been following an [Introduction to Angular Test Driven Development](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-angular-test-driven-development) tutorial.

I am failing at the first hurdle, before I've written any tests.

When I run `karma start` from the `tutorial/` directory I get the error:

> Karma v 6.3.2 - connected; test: karma_error An error was thrown in afterAll Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined ReferenceError: angular is not defined at http://localhost:9876/base/app/app.js

How do I get Angular to load?

My current understanding is that `angular` should load automatically because of the `files: []` line in `karma.conf.js` and `app.js` should have access to it. At the moment my `app.js` is creating a basic controller and nothing else and as far I can tell my code matches the code in the tutorial for this stage. The tutorial has a [Git Hub repository](https://github.com/hggeorgiev/angular-tests).

Based on the tutorial, my directory structure is as follows:

```
tutorial/
|-app/
|---app.js
|-karma.conf.js
|-node_modules/ [Only listing relevant files]
|---angular/
|------angular.js
|---angular-mocks/
|------angular-mocks.js
|-package.json
|-tests/
|--[empty dir]
```

This is my entire `app/app.js`:

```js
angular.module('ItemsApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.title = 'Items App Title'
    });
```

And this is my `karma.conf.js`:

```js
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'app/**.js',
      'tests/**.js',
      'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
      'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'
    ],


    // list of files / patterns to exclude
    exclude: [
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,


    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial suggests you give paths of your application in the wrong order when running `karma init`.

As `app/app.js` depends on `node_modules/angular/angular.js`, the latter should be declared first. To fix the problem, update `karma.conf.js` to declare:

```js
    files: [
      'node_modules/angular/angular.js',
      'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/**.js',
      'tests/**.js'
    ],
```

This is the order shown in the tutorial's sample file, but not the order that (on my system) was generated when I  followed the instructions in the tutorial for running `karma init`.